# printf not printing special characters

Tags: c, printf, special-characters

I'm trying to make a simple card game but after switching from Win 7 to Xubuntu 14.04 even the most simple things do not work anymore. I tried this for 3 days and still can't solve it.
What happens is that the console is giving me 3 diamond question marks, for the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define herz    "\xe2\x99\xa5"
#define karo    "\xe2\x99\xa6"
#define kreuz   "\xe2\x99\xa3"
#define pik     "\xe2\x99\xa0"

int main()
{
char ch = '0';
printf("%c%c%c%c",herz,karo,kreuz,pik);
return 0;
}
```

I tried this with the code:blocks console and the xubuntu one.

```
(xterm -T $TITLE -e and xfce4-terminal -T $TITLE -x)
```

Console LANG is `en_US.UTF-8`.

I tried several fonts and it didn't change a thing. I can type in special characters manually in the console but when C tries to print them it does not work.

Comment: `%c` is not for strings

Comment: Use `%s` to print C-strings.

Comment: It also depends on the terminal that is running the program

Comment: Wow thanks guys. Works now. Really stupid mistake by me. Thanks. Can Mod close this before I feel shame? :)

Comment: gcc should have warned about the incorrect argument type for `%c` format.  Always eliminate warnings before posting questions here.

Comment: Nothing special about these characters. If anything, ASCII characters are special.

Comment: @HermannDesu : There is no shame, and the question should not be closed or deleted.  It is a useful contribution to SO's knowledge base.

Answer (score 3):

`%c` is used to print single characters. Since you are trying to print strings, use `%s` instead. Your print statement will be

```
wprintf("%s%s%s%s",herz,karo,kreuz,pik);
```

Comment: But he wants to print a *single* UTF-8 character.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined literal constant *character strings* where you need literal constant *wide characters*.

```
const wchar_t herz = L'\ue299a5';
```

You then need to print using `wprintf()` with the `%lc` format specifier:

```
wprintf("%lc%lc%lc%lc", herz, karo, kreuz, pikl) ;
```

Comment: This doesn't work under gcc 4.1.2.  It says "character constant too long for its type".